# if statement hover syntax error message

Tags: jquery, html, css, if-statement, touch

I'm trying to say if the movement is down and the movement is a certain length then make the opacity of the image darker but with this code I'm getting a syntax error:

```
    function touchMove(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) && (swipeDirection == 'down') && (swipeLength >= 90) && (swipeLength <= 120){
            curX = event.touches[0].pageX;
            curY = event.touches[0].pageY;
        ('1.png').hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": .5 });
        }}
            // OPTIONAL ACTION: draw the results to the page
            updateReadout(2) 
        } else {
            touchCancel(event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave your code a [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com) spin

```
function touchMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ((event.touches.length === 1) && (swipeDirection === 'down') && (swipeLength >= 90) && (swipeLength <= 120)) {
        curX = event.touches[0].pageX;
        curY = event.touches[0].pageY;
        ('1.png').hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                "opacity": '.5'
            });
        });
        // OPTIONAL ACTION: draw the results to the page
        updateReadout(2);
    } else {
        touchCancel(event);
    }
}
```

There were several syntax errors (missing ) and ; among other things). Also, the updateReadout(2) call was outside the `if` and then followed by a lonely `else`, so I fixed that according to how I figured it should work but you should definitely double check.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate the effort.

Answer (score 0):

A little more detail as to what the syntax error is would be helpful.

On first glance though you need a set of brackets to group your if statement

```
    if ((event.touches.length == 1) && (swipeDirection == 'down') && (swipeLength >= 90) && (swipeLength <= 120)) {
```

Secondly the selector you're using `1.png` i assume is the src of the image element? In which case it should be

```
$('IMG[src*=1.png]').hover(function() {
```

However selecting based on the image name is very unreliable. For example, the above would match 1.png, and also 11.png, 21.png etc. If you can change this to be a class or id selector, or traverse the DOM from the touched element to find the image.

There could possibly be other issues in the code, but that should hopefully fix the syntax problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( event.touches.length == 1 ) && (swipeDirection == 'down') && (swipeLength >= 90) && (swipeLength <= 120){
```

should be

```
if ( event.touches.length == 1 && swipeDirection == 'down' && swipeLength >= 90 && swipeLength <= 120){
```

parentheses issues

Answer (score 0):

In this part:

```
('1.png').hover(function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": .5 });
        }}
```

as well as fixing the selector (per Rory's answer), the last line should be `});`:

```
$('IMG[src*=1.png]').hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": .5 });
});
```